# How to use getDirection() properly with PointerLockControls in Three.js

Tags: three.js, pointerlock

I'm using `PointerLockControls` in `Three.js`.

On mouse click, I want to update a sphere position to the position the camera is facing, at the same `z-position` of a certain object. I've read about `getDirection()`, but can't seem to implement it the right way. Here's what I tried:

```
var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3();
mouse3D.normalize();
controls.getDirection( mouse3D );
sphere.position.x = mouse3D.x;
sphere.position.y = mouse3D.y;
sphere.position.z = object.position.z;
```

The `z-position` is fine, but x and y are so close to 0 that the sphere stays "on the ground" and doesn't go "left or right".

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

direction is a normalized vector (length is 1)

you have to find factor so that `camera.position + direction * factor` gives vector with `z = object.position.z`

`factor = (object.position.z - camera.position.z)/direction.z`

and just multiply your mouse3D vector `mouse3D.multiplyScalar(factor)`

Comment: I tried `var factor = (object.position.z - camera.position.z)/mouse3D.z;
mouse3D.multiplyScalar(factor);` . This seems to put the sphere at the right x position, but the y position is still off. The sphere always appears beneath of where I clicked... any thoughts? Also, the moment I start moving my character (like in a first person shooter), the x position isn't correct either.

Comment: you have to add the camera position to the resulting position `sphere.position = camera.position.clone().add(mouse3D)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't seem to fix the issues I mentioned above.